# best way to store member of group in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database-design, storing-data

I am developing an android application where people will sign up and join groups.
I have a separate MySQL table which stores details of the users and another table which stores details of groups. But I have problem relating users to groups. 
The users table will have his `user_id`, `name`, `password`, `email_id`, `address`, etc. The group table will have the `group_id`, `group_name` and other details regarding the group.
I must be able to get

1. all the users who are in a group
2. all the groups which a user has joined

quickly and easily.

Note: Assume you have over a 100k users and over 1000 groups.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic way of doing this would be to have an additional n:m mapping table, which just holds pairs of IDs - a user and a group he or she belongs to:

```
CREATE TABLE group_membership (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    group_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (id)
)
```

And now, e.g., if you wish to query all the users from `my_group`, you could do so with a couple of joins:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   users u
JOIN   group_membership gm ON u.id = gm.user_id
JOIN   groups g ON gm.group_id = g.id
WHERE  g.name = 'my_group'
```

Comment: I am afraid this will increase the storage complexity .

Comment: @SenthilVidhiyakar well, it will not increase much because just storing int. (ids) nothing else, but its the best solution to handle many2many relation.

Comment: Every user would join n groups and the max no of entries in the group_membership table would go up to NoOfEntriesInUser*NoOfGroups

Comment: Thanks for the solution. would be grateful If I get a little better solution..!!

Comment: This is the correct approach. If you want something different, don't use an RDBMS.